# PHP: foreach loop resulting in "Illegal Offset" Error

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am making a web application, I am trying to use a foreach loop and I have run into some problems.

**Example**

```
$arr = array(
   'username' => 'Test',
   'password' => 'Cheese',
);
foreach($arr as $arr2){
    echo $arr2['username'];
}
```

That will output this:

Warning: Illegal string offset 'username' in **PATH** on line 8
T

Warning: Illegal string offset 'username' in **PATH** on line 8
C

Does anyone know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The array you have described does not really warrant a foreach loop. You can simply do:

`echo $arr['username'];`

If your intention is to loop through all the different bits of data, then you can do this:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . ': ' . $value . '<BR>';
}
```

Which will output something like:

```
username: Test
password: Cheese
```

More info on [PHP's manual page for arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr = array(
'username' => 'Test',
'password' => 'Cheese',
);
echo $arr['username'];
echo $arr['password'];
?>
```

does not require foreach